# Why is my function not displaying the outcome of the Pi Camera?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have the function:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def getImg(display = False, size=[640,480]):
_,img = cap.read()
    img =cv2.resize(img,(size[0],size[1]))
    if display == True:
        cv2.imshow('IMG',img)
    return img
```

Where if i call this function for example: Webcam.getImg(display =True). I would like it to display a live feed of the Pi camera however when i do this it does not, how can i rectify this code so it displays the output of the Pi camera?

Comment: try to add `cv2.waitKey(0)` after `cv2.imshow()`? also, do you have a loop where you call `getImg` somewhere inside it?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in some of the comments on your post, you need to add `cv2.waitKey(0)` (it stops the execution to show the imshow result) or `cv2.waitKey(30)` ( it waits 30 ms to show the results and continue. Typically used if you are in a loop to grab the frames from the webcam).

Take a look to the docs: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7

Cheers.